# Nested promises while using Array.map, using Promise.all but still not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, promise

I've been banging my head against a wall for some time now. I have some node code that pulls a bunch of googlecalendar events and then maps these onto a different object structure for use in my webapp... As part of this I need to match the users in the google calendar event with the users in my webapp's database. Here's the code:

```
router.post('/getCalendar', function(req,res) {  
  // authentication
  var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
  var session = req.session;
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: req.user.google.token,
    refresh_token: req.user.google.refreshToken,
    expiry_date: true
  })

  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // get the next 20 calendar events   
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
      calendar.events.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 20,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) console.log('err',err)
          // displays all the events
        if (response) console.log('response',response)
        if(response) {
          var events = response.items;
          resolve(events || err);  
        }        
    });

  }).then(function (data) {

    var newdata = data.map(function(item) {
      // create the new object structure and populate with some details
      newObj = {
          _id: item.id,
          _title: item.summary,
          group: [req.headers.group],
          fields: [],
          assignedTo: [],
          google: "calendar",
          googledata: item,
          _category: []
      }

      var extendedFields = {}

      // get the list of attendees
      attendees = item.attendees.map(function(user) {
        var attendee = user.email;
        return attendee;
      })

      // pulls the user information for each attendee using promises
      var promises = attendees.map(function(email) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

          // data is in a mongodb, using mongoose
          User.findOne({'google.email': email}).exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) return resolve(null);
            resolve(user); //not using reject at all so the Promise.all shouldn't fail
          });
        })
      })

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function(value) {
          value.forEach(function(user) {
            if(promise !== null) {
              newObj.assignedTo.push(user);  
            }
          });

          return newObj

      }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})

  })

  res.json(newdata)
  })

});
```

I am using Promise.all to wait till all the promises have resolved, but it seems to move onto the next item in the `data` array before completing the first. Any guidance would be welcome. Please let me know if more details are required.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to `reject` when there is no response

Comment: You need to use `Promise.all` and `map` for the `data` array as well

Comment: @Bergi - I thought that when I use `reject`, then `Promise.all` will fail... I'm also not sure how to use Promise.all for `map` and `data` as you suggest. Can you please provide some more explanation or an example?

Comment: I mean the `calendar.events.list` call - if you don't settle the promise (either fulfill or reject), it will hang forever.

Comment: You already did fine for `attendees` - just do the same for the `data` array now. `return` the "inner" `Promise.all(…)` promise from the `map` callback so that `newdata` is an array of promises again

Comment: @Bergi OK. Thank you! This solved my problem. There is an answer now that does just what you said but shows the code for it. Should I just accept it?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. return promise of last Promise.all.

   ```
   return Promise.all(promises)
       .then(function(value) {
         value.forEach(function(user) {
           // user !== null ? 
           if(promise !== null) {
             newObj.assignedTo.push(user);  
           }
         });

         return newObj
       })
       .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
   ```
2. use Promise.all on newdata.

   ```
   Promise.all(newdata)
     .then(function (newObjs) {
       // newObjs is the Array of newObj in your code
       res.json(newObjs);
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
     });
   ```